# Would not print out the line number of query

Tags: python, search, text-files

I have two txt files in a folder: docs and queries.
In docs.txt, note the lines are separate:

`joyously urgently truthfully seemingly broadly urgently relatively upwardly vaguely hardly rudely acidly knowingly urgently`

`joyously urgently truthfully seemingly rigidly simply dramatically totally broadly rigidly suddenly healthily commonly often`

`tremendously more sharply totally steadily righteously rarely`

and in queries.txt:

`urgently`

`rigidly suddenly`

`totally steadily`

and I have this python code:

```
relevant = []
def main():
    searchandvalue()


def searchandvalue():
    line_number=0
    searchquery= open('queries.txt', 'r')
    with open('docs.txt', 'r') as open1a:
        for query in searchquery:
            print('query word: ', query)
            for word in open1a:
                line_number+=1
                if query in word:
                    relevant.append(line_number)

            print('relevant', relevant)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What supposed to output is this:

```
query word:  urgently

relevant [1, 2]
query word:  rigidly suddenly

relevant [2]
query word:  totally steadily
relevant [3]
```

Instead, I have this:
What supposed to output is this:

```
query word:  urgently

relevant []
query word:  rigidly suddenly

relevant []
query word:  totally steadily
relevant []
```

How do I solve this

Comment: Welcome to SO! For me it outputs `relevant [1]` every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with reading your files. By iterating over your file with a for loop you have trailing newlines and the file cursor is at the end of the file after iterating through the file once. That's why I suggest you read your files first and split them into lines.

```
with open("queries.txt", "r") as open_queries:
    # read from file and split into a list of lines
    searchquery = open_queries.read().split("\n")

with open('docs.txt', 'r') as open1a:
    # read from file and split into a list of lines
    words = open1a.read().split("\n")
```

Now you can process the queries. Remember to reset the current `relevant` and `line_number` before processing a new `query`.

```
for query in searchquery:
    print('query word:', query)
    # reset relevant list and line_number 
    relevant = []
    line_number = 0
    for word in words:
        line_number += 1
        if query in word:
            relevant.append(line_number)
    print('relevant', relevant)
```